# Двусоставный или двухсоставный?

Tags: орфография

"Двусоставный" или "двухсоставный"?
Какой вариант является верным, предпочтительным и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Словари дают только **двусоставный**.
Но это в значении "состоящий из двух элементов". В лингвистике, например.
Я не уверен, что вы именно эим значением интересуетесь. 
Возможно у химиков или там на железной дороге, где может идти речь о **двух составах**, есть свои соображения на этот счет.